# Create a share sheet in iOS 15 with swiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, share, ios15

I am trying to create a share sheet to share a `Text`, it was working fine in iOS 14 but in iOS 15 it tells me that

> 'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a
> relevant window scene instead.

how can I make it work on iOS 15 with SwiftUI

```
Button {
    let TextoCompartido = "Hola  "
    
    let AV = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [TextoCompartido], applicationActivities: nil)
    
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(AV, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You should try this UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate?.window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing 'UIActivityViewController' in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533564/showing-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 16):

I think you would be best served using SwiftUI APIs directly. Generally, I would follow these steps.

1. Create SwiftUI `View` named `ActivityView` that adheres to `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. This will allow you to bring `UIActivityViewController` to SwiftUI.
2. Create an `Identifiable` struct to contain the text you'd like to display in the `ActivityView`. Making this type will allow you to use the SwiftUI [sheet API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) and leverage SwiftUI state to tell the app when a new `ActivityView` to be shown.
3. Create an optional `@State` variable that will hold on to your `Identifiable` text construct. When this variable changes, the [sheet API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) will perform the callback.
4. When the button is tapped, update the state of the variable set in step 3.
5. Use the [sheet API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) to create an `ActivityView` which will be presented to your user.

The code below should help get you started.

---

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

// 1. Activity View
struct ActivityView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let text: String

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityView>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        return UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityView>) {}
}

// 2. Share Text
struct ShareText: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // 3. Share Text State
    @State var shareText: ShareText?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Activity View") {
                // 4. New Identifiable Share Text
                shareText = ShareText(text: "Hola ")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        // 5. Sheet to display Share Text
        .sheet(item: $shareText) { shareText in
            ActivityView(text: shareText.text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the optional `@State` variable to compile, so i ended up using the following solution wich is very similar but uses a bool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58341956/2107610

Comment: This code is producing bottom safe area spacing. Did you manage to fix that?

Answer (score 5):

Tested in in iOS 15 with SwiftUI

```
 func shareViaActionSheet() {
        if vedioData.vedioURL != nil {
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [vedioData.vedioURL as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.currentUIWindow()?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

To avoid iOS 15 method deprecation warning use this extension

```
public extension UIApplication {
    func currentUIWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        let connectedScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
        
        let window = connectedScenes.first?
            .windows
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        return window
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing on iPad, and crashes with "UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs."

Answer (score 3):

iOS 16 includes the `ShareLink` view which works like this:

```
Gallery(...)
   .toolbar {
      ShareLink(item: image, preview: SharePreview("Birthday Effects"))
   }
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10052/

Time code offset: 25 minutes 28 seconds

Comment: there's nothing about the `ShareLink` at 20:17...

Comment: It clearly asked for iOS 15

Comment: For those upvoting: "It clearly asked for iOS 15", this is true, but question was asked before iOS 16 was released. This answer was provided just after iOS 16 beta was released, so those seeking how to do this knew there was a non-UIKit bridging solution - which is definitely preferable (if you are OK to only support iOS 16 and newer). Context matters.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following using the answer from: [How to get rid of message " 'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead" with AdMob banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650504/how-to-get-rid-of-message-windows-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0-use-uiwindowsc)

Note that your code works for me, but the compiler give the deprecation warning.

```
public extension UIApplication {
    func currentUIWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        let connectedScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({
                $0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
            .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        
        let window = connectedScenes.first?
            .windows
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }

        return window
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let TextoCompartido = "Hola  "
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let AV = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [TextoCompartido], applicationActivities: nil)
 
 UIApplication.shared.currentUIWindow()?.rootViewController?.present(AV, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
// This works for me, but the compiler give the deprecation warning
// UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(AV, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }) {
            Text("Hola click me")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be very wary to follow this advice because you should not be able to depend on SwiftUI leveraging UIKit in the same way in subsequent releases.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid warning, change the way you retrieve the window scene.
Do the following:

```
Button {
   let TextoCompartido = "Hola  "
                                
   let AV = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [TextoCompartido], applicationActivities: nil)
    
   let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
   let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    
   windowScene?.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(AV, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: This code works very well for me, for the second time, third time, etc... However, for the first time (after deploying on a phone or simulator) it freezes the UI for a long while and I see such messages on the console like "[Default] Task ... couldn't find entitlement CopresenceCore.Entitlement.publicAPI error nil". Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: warp it with a  DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Answer (score 0):

// iOS 16+, Swift 5

```
var rootViewController: UIViewController? {
    let connectedScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
        .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
    let window = connectedScenes.first?.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
    let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController
    return rootViewController
}

func topViewController(of viewController: UIViewController? = rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(of: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tabController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(of: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = viewController?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(of: presented)
    }
    return viewController
}
```